# IConfidentialClientApplication AcquireTokenForClient exception being thrown periodically

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I built a NotificationService factory for checking 2 different mailboxes. Everything works fine but periodically I receive an error email. Below is the method throwing the exception and the exception message itself

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        try { 
            string token = string.Empty;
            IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_settings.AzureClientID)
            .WithCertificate(_settings.Certificate)
            .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_settings.AzureTenantID}")
            .WithRedirectUri("https://daemon")
            .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: Exception within GetAccessToken\r\n{ex}", ex);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

2/8/2023 9:28:19 AM: Exception within GetAccessToken
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithNtAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean isProxyAuth, HttpConnection connection, HttpConnectionPool connectionPool, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.ExecuteAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, HttpMethod method, ILoggerAdapter logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.ExecuteWithRetryAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, HttpMethod method, ILoggerAdapter logger, Boolean doNotThrow, Boolean retry, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.SendPostAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, ILoggerAdapter logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.SendPostAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, IDictionary`2 bodyParameters, ILoggerAdapter logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ExecuteRequestAsync[T](Uri endPoint, HttpMethod method, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean expectErrorsOn200OK, Boolean addCommonHeaders, Func`2 onBeforePostRequestData) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.GetTokenAsync(Uri endPoint, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean addCommonHeaders, Func`2 onBeforePostRequestHandler)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendHttpAndClearTelemetryAsync(String tokenEndpoint, ILoggerAdapter logger)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendTokenRequestAsync(IDictionary`2 additionalBodyParameters, String scopeOverride, String tokenEndpointOverride, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.FetchNewAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenForClientParameters clientParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at HIW.NotificationService.Service.GraphService.GetAccessToken() in C:\agent_work\60\s\HIW.NotificationService\Service\GraphService.cs:line 276